# unable to get sku on product description tab

Tags: product

I tried to show sku on product description tab on product detail page, I put below code:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_sku, 'sku') ?>
```

on `catalog/customer/view/description.phtml`

But it does not work.

Please check if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You did a small mistake. Use

```
$this->getProduct()->getSku()
```

instead of `$_sku`

This is because, when you are in product view page, `$this->getProduct()` will returns current product instance in the description block.

Comment: Did some modification on your answer in order clear the point. I hope you won't mind